# Write a Collector or nest existing ones

Tags: java, lambda, collectors

I have a method in a data Structure that I wish to use to pass various collectors and apply them to my object.

The following is the Method -->

```
 public <R> R applyCollector(String key, Collector a)
    {
        this.key = key;
        this.a = a;
        R result = (R) this.stateList.stream().
                map(state -> state.getKey(key)).collect(a);
        return  result;
    }
```

The above method basically takes in a "key" and a Collector that it applies over the values got by key.

This is the way I'm using it -->

```
Collector stringToListCollector =
               Collectors.toList();
List<String> values =
               myObject.applyCollector("key",
                       stringToListCollector);
```

This works fine for simple things like getting count, average etc.

But, what if I wish to send something more complex, like a Nested Collector.
For example, say my "key" returns me a String, which is actually an IP or even an Integer.

What I'd like to do is to send a collector that first Converts my String to Integer by doing a "integer::parseInt" and then doing the toList.

Right now I have to first retrieve a list named values (defined above). And then do a `values.stream().Map(Integer::ParseString).collect(Collectors::averagingInt).`

I might need to do this operation multiple times, I have two options.

1. Make the ToList and Map and Collect as a function. and call it. This
   beats my purpose of lambda.
2. Write or nest existing Collectors to directly do that for me. This
       option looks neater to me because if I can do it correctly, I'll be
       able to do everything in One Pass instead of the 2 passes it takes
       me now, as well as maybe save the Memory I need to first create a
       list.

How do I do this? Write a Collector that does -->

- Gets an object, and runs Integer::ParseInt upon it and then do an
  Average Operation.

Comment: Your stream looks a little off. It should look like this: `values.stream().collect(Collectors.averagingInt(Integer::parseInt))`

Comment: I cannot do that because I want to pass my collector as an argument. I am unable to construct my Collector as Collectors.averagingInt(Integer::parseInt))

Comment: Collector k = Collectors.averagingInt(Integer::parseInt); will not work because this is not a valid way to get a method reference out. Or am I doing something wrong?

I need a method reference, for which I'm doing this. Collector k = Collectors::averagingInt;
I pass "k" to my method then.

Comment: @shmosel,  I can do this, if I had to stream in my own method (Read Option 1).
Which I do not want to do. I want to wrap everything in a Single collector if possible and If possible not write my own brand new collector. I wish that everything happens by passing my collector as a method so that I do not have to write what you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example it would look like

```
applyCollector("key", mapping(Integer::parseInt, averagingInt(i -> i))
```

Collectors can be composed to some extend:

- `Collectors.mapping` executes function before collecting
- `Collectors.collectingAndThen` executes function after collecting

additionally some collectors accept downstream collectors i.e `groupingBy`

Comment: This is exactly what I want. I can probably nest CollectAndThen a few times because it seems like mapping(takes another collector). I'll need to experiment but it seems like this should do the trick.